# How to boot windows after installing ubuntu? (ubuntu does detect windows, just doesn't allow me to boot it)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

im absolutely new to linux (this is my first day using ubuntu 14.04). I installed ubuntu on my system in dual boot mode. When I start ubuntu I do not get the option to choose my OS as most tutorials on internet had me believe. My computer directly boots into ubuntu. 
I don't think windows has been corrupted, as OS prober does show windows 8

```
jumani@jumani-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo os-prober
/dev/sda1:Windows 8 (loader):Windows:chain
```

I tried to use commands to use boot repair but they don't seem to work. I keep getting errors when

```
 I use sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

The error comes after I use sudo apt-get update command

```
W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And after that obiously apt-get install command doesn't work either.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix your package system first.

Looks like your sources file is corrupted so let's start with this.

Delete `sources.list` by running this command.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Regenerate your sources.list by opening up a terminal and typing

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Tick all the software sources like so :

[image]

Change the main server to your country and click close.

[image]

Then click Reload.

[image]

Wait for that to finish ...

Now we come to getting dual boot to work.

Open a terminal and run this command :

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you for help, it seems to have worked fine except for the fact that I got a warning. Should I be worried? –

Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.

Comment: @MuhammadSaadJumani no you should not be worried

Answer (score 0):

Press Esc a lot of times for a short time while booting, there should be a menu to boot Windows (Its called grub.)